# I have a controller class in which I want to delete the selected records and make exception record as a hyperlink

Tags: exception, error-messages

it throws exception as a statement but I want to make the exception record Id as hyperlink so that when I click on the link it will redirect to detail page of  related record

code is:

```
for(integer i = 0; i < ex.getNumDML(); i++) {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(
        ApexPages.severity.error, ex.getDmlMessage(i)) );
}
```

VF page code:
     `<apex:pageMessages escape="false"  />`[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the `DeleteResult` **[class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_deleteresult.htm)**, in which you can check if  the delete statement was successful, and if it was not, you can get the error message and the Id.

And if you set to `false` the `escape` attribute in your `pageMessages` tag, you'll be able to add links using a snippet like this:

```
ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, '<a href="/' + record_id + '">test</a>');
```

Comment: Your attempt to delete Burlington Textiles Corp of America could not be completed because it is associated with the following cases.: 00001019, 00001020 Your attempt to delete Burlington Textiles Corp of America could not be completed because some opportunities in that account were closed won. The opportunities that could not be deleted are shown below.: Burlington Textiles Weaving Plant Generator

Comment: I want to make this error msg in which 00001019 be a hyperlink so when i click on it ,it will goes to the detail page of case

Comment: Then map the account's (Id) cases to their codes (String) in a `Map<Id, List<String>>`, and on the error message (like in my example) you can replace 'test' with the case number. Something like `ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, '<a href="/' + record_id + '">' + map_with_case_names.get(record_id) + '</a>');`

Comment: how to get record id dynamically when the record have child objects